# Array b are equal to the sum the digit of the array element a

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop, numbers

I need help solving this problem, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The task is: *Write a program that loads an array `a` of `n` natural numbers and then forms an array `b` so that the elements of the array `b` are equal to the sum the digits of the array element `a`.*

```
Example:
n=5
a[0]=1
a[1]=2
a[2]=3
a[3]=32
a[4]=54
Array b is:
b[0]=1
b[1]=2
b[2]=3
b[3]=5
b[4]=9
```

I did like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 100

void form(int [], int [], int);
int sum_digit(int);
void print (int [], int);

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n < 1 || n > MAX) {
        int n;
        printf("Enter n:");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }
    int a[MAX], b[MAX];
    printf("Enter element of array a:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d. element:",i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    form(a, b, n);
    print(b, n);
    return 0;
}

void form(int a[MAX], int b[MAX], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        while (a[i] > 0) {
            int pom = a[i] % 10;
            b[i] = sum_digit(pom);
            a[i] = a[i] / 10;
        }
    }
}

int sum_digit(int s) {
    int sum = 0;
    sum = sum + s;
    return sum;
}

void print(int b[MAX], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem arises for multi-digit array elements.
Each time the `sum_digit` function is called the sum is set to zero.
So for example for element `32`, I can't get 5 because I can't add `2` and `3`. If anyone has an idea how to solve this I would be grateful.

Comment: Why do you need a `sum_digit()` function? Initialize `b[i]` to `0` and then just add `pom` to it each time through the `while` loop.

Comment: The task says that I have to use the  sum_digit()  function.
I did not state that in this post

Comment: Why 100? Why not 101?

Comment: Then the function is supposed to calculate the entire sum -- the loop should be in that function, not the caller.

Comment: The task states that I have to do this with the help of the three functions listed: void form(int [],int [],int);
int sum_digit(int);
void print (int [],int); 
As we can see the sum_digit () function has no parameter for the array.

Comment: @PCSafe Are we really *all* the legend? :)

Comment: @PCSafe "The task states that I have to do this with (some condition) " --> Rather than later post that new requirement in a comment, either appreciate answers that do not use that tardy spec or add such requirements to the question - best initially.  Else the question becomes a moving target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not test the return value of `scanf()` so any invalid or missing input will cause undefined behavior because the destination variables will not be updated.
- There is a new variable `n` defined in the `while` loop, so the original variable in the outer scope is never modified by `scanf()`.
- `form` and `sum_digit` are both incorrect: you should compute the sum in `sum_digit()` with a loop and store all sums in a loop in `form`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 100

void form(int [], int [], int);
int sum_digits(int);
void print (int [], int);

int main() {
    int n;
    
    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter n:");
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
            return 1;
        if (n >= 1 && n <= MAX)
            break;
        printf("Incorrect value: %d\n", n);
    }
    int a[MAX], b[MAX];
    printf("Enter elements of array a:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d. element:", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    form(a, b, n);
    print(b, n);
    return 0;
}

void form(int a[MAX], int b[MAX], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b[i] = sum_digits(a[i]);
    }
}

int sum_digits(int s) {
    int sum = 0;

    /* this loop handles positive and negative numbers alike */
    while (s != 0) {
        sum = sum + s % 10;
        s = s / 10;
    }
    /* return the positive sum of digits */
    return abs(sum);
}

void print(int b[MAX], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @PCSafe: I added simple support for negative numbers: most people forget about those...

Comment: Minor: In order to call `abs()` only once: `while (s != 0) { sum = sum + s % 10; s = s / 10; } return abs(sum);`.

Comment: @chqrlie The assignment says you don't need to worry about negative numbers (look up the definition of "natural number").

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: +1 we should meet some time for supper and share thoughts on computing and conciseness :)

Comment: @Barmar: indeed *natural numbers* are not negative... I remember learning about ℕ in 1972, but did not actually encounter the formal definition from Dedekind (who did not include 0) until 1978.  I overlooked that part of the question, but it is valuable insight to learn about the sign of remainders of integer divisions of negative numbers.

Comment: True, but I suspect that the assignment specifically said natural numbers to avoid having to deal with this wrinkle at this stage in the student's education. They wanted to limit the scope of the exercise.

Comment: @Barmar Trouble is that functions named and signatured as `int sum_digits(int s)` do not convey that distant _natural numbers_ limitation.  Lacking local comments, code speaks for itself and `int sum_digits(int s)` benefits with a design that handles the full range of `s` for others that see this code.

Answer (score 2):

For starters pay attention to that as the type of elements of the array a is `int` then it means that the user can enter negative numbers in the array. But the sum of digits should be a non-negative value.

And the array `a` should not be changed. The task is just to form the array `b`.

Now here you are.

```
void form( const int a[], int b[], int n ) 
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        b[i] = sum_digit( a[i] );
    }
}
```

and

```
int sum_digit( int num )
{
    enum { Base = 10 };

    int sum = 0;

    do
    {
        int digit = num % Base;
        if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;
        sum += digit;
    } while ( num /= Base );

    return sum;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_digit( int );

void form( const int a[], int b[], int n )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = sum_digit( a[i] );
    }
}

int sum_digit( int num )
{
    enum { Base = 10 };

    int sum = 0;

    do
    {
        int digit = num % Base;
        if (digit < 0) digit = -digit;
        sum += digit;
    } while (num /= Base);

    return sum;
}

void print( const int a[], int n )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void )
{
    enum { MAX = 5 };
    int a[MAX] = { 1, -22, 333, -4444, 55555 };
    int b[MAX];

    print( a, MAX );

    form( a, b, MAX );

    print( b, MAX );
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -22 333 -4444 55555
1 4 9 16 25
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're the Legend ! :)

Comment: @PCSafe See my appended post.

Comment: @PCSafe Try your program with the array shown in my answer.:)

Comment: `if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;` could effectively be moved after the loop: `if ( sum < 0 ) sum = -sum;`.

Comment: The assignment says "natural numbers", so negative numbers are not possible input. You could change the declaration to `unsigned` to make this clear.

Comment: @Barmar Yes if so then the array should be declared with the element type unsigned int.

Answer (score 1):

`sum_digit()` should calculate the sum of all the digits, not just one digit. So you need to move the loop from `form()` to `sum_digit()`.

```
void form(int a[MAX],int b[MAX],int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        b[i]=sum_digit(a[i]);
    }
}

int sum_digit(int s)
{
    int sum=0;
    while (s > 0) {
        sum += s % 10;
        s /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Since the assignment says that the array contains natural numbers, you could also change all your `int` declarations to `unsigned`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're the Legend ! :)

Comment: `while (s > 0)` will not sum digits well when `s < 0`.  Perhaps OP does not care about that.

Comment: The assignment says "array of natural numbers". Negative numbers are not natural.

Comment: @Barmar: sure, but then `int` does not quite cover the range of *natural numbers* :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should update the answer to use the GMP library, it comes closest.

Comment: I'm afraid you inner loop in `form` is going to run forever in most cases :)